# I wonder why asset_manager(android ndk) have no interface to traverse directory

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Currently I am coding with android NDK and C++.

But I could not understand why asset_manager have no interface to traverse directory.
[here interface](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___asset.html)

I wanna get file names from directory recursively.

but

AAssetManager_openDir
AAssetDir_getNextFileName

function get only file  except directory.

How to get all filename from directory and subdirectory recursively?

Answer (score 0):

The AssetManager provides access to a resource bundle. It is not a directory structured data storage, like a traditional file system, therefore, it has no API methods dealing with directories.

Comment: there is no way than asset_manager?   other method is not exist?